# Best Practise: Headless Magento2 Authentication For Login

Tags: magento2, headless, customer-login

Please could someone provide the best practise or documentation for how it can be achieved that the customer may login via Google, Facebook, etc when the Magento framework is only being used in a headless way?

I am aware that it runs on OAuth so I am hoping that there is a mechanism within OAuth which supports this? Please point me in the correct direction for this.

(NOT AUTHENTICATING API REQUESTS)